# SharedPreferences are not deleted with app

Tags: android

When I uninstall my app, and then reinstall it, it opens with the values that are in the `SharedPreferences`. That means that the `SharedPreferences` were not deleted. How can the `SharedPreferences` be made to delete together with the app?

Comment: Which device do you use?

Comment: they are backed up to the user's google drive by default. You can disable autoBackup in manifest

Comment: That worked. Dankjewel, Tim.

Answer (score 2):

Set allowBackup to false in android manifest like this

```
<application
            android:name="com.example.Application"
            android:allowBackup="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had this issue and i had tried disabling backing in the manifest also,

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="false"
```

which also didn't work for me in Xiaomi Mi phones and it got cleared only when I restarted the phone.(Probably because of over customization by them.)